# Combine rotation and translation in opencv, in one pass

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform

I have a piece of code for rotating and translating image:

```
Point2f pt(0, in.rows);
double angle = atan(trans.c / trans.b) * 180 / M_PI;
Mat r = getRotationMatrix2D(pt, -angle, 1.0);
warpAffine(in, out, r, in.size(), interpolation); /* rotation */

Mat t = (Mat_<double>(2, 3) << 1, 0, trans.a, 0, 1, -trans.d);
warpAffine(out, out, t, in.size(), interpolation); /* translation */
```

The problem is that I'm doing this in two times. So if I have an angle of 90degree for example, the first "out" variable will be empty because all data are out of bounds. Is there a way to do it in one pass ? In order to avoid loosing my data and having black image.

I think that the best thing would be to combine r and t in one matrix but I'm a little lost.

Best regards,

Comment: you can simply multiplay homographies. Affine transformation has to be extended to 3x3 to do that by adding a 3rd row: 0 0 1 then you can simply multiply Hcombined = H1 * H2; But be careful that you multiply in the right order.

Comment: OK, Thanks. How I simply can add a 3rd row to r with opencv ? Then I am not sure to understand what is H1 and what is H2. H1 is the rotation matrix with the 3rd row added ? H2 is the translation matrix ?

Comment: I'll post a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to combine 2 homographies by simple multiplication and how to extract an affine transformation from a 3x3 homography.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png");

    // create to 3x3 identity homography matrices
    cv::Mat homography1 = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Mat homography2 = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64FC1);

    double alpha1 = -13; // degrees
    double t1_x = -86; // pixel
    double t1_y = -86; // pixel

    double alpha2 = 21; // degrees
    double t2_x = 86; // pixel
    double t2_y = 86; // pixel

    // hope there is no error in the signs:
    // combine homography1
    homography1.at<double>(0, 0) = cos(CV_PI*alpha1 / 180);
    homography1.at<double>(0, 1) = -sin(CV_PI*alpha1 / 180);
    homography1.at<double>(1, 0) = sin(CV_PI*alpha1 / 180);
    homography1.at<double>(1, 1) = cos(CV_PI*alpha1 / 180);
    homography1.at<double>(0, 2) = t1_x;
    homography1.at<double>(1, 2) = t1_y;

    // compose homography2
    homography2.at<double>(0, 0) = cos(CV_PI*alpha2 / 180);
    homography2.at<double>(0, 1) = -sin(CV_PI*alpha2 / 180);
    homography2.at<double>(1, 0) = sin(CV_PI*alpha2 / 180);
    homography2.at<double>(1, 1) = cos(CV_PI*alpha2 / 180);
    homography2.at<double>(0, 2) = t2_x;
    homography2.at<double>(1, 2) = t2_y;

    cv::Mat affine1 = homography1(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 2));
    cv::Mat affine2 = homography2(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 2));

    cv::Mat dst1;
    cv::Mat dst2;

    cv::warpAffine(input, dst1, affine1, input.size());
    cv::warpAffine(input, dst2, affine2, input.size());


    cv::Mat combined_homog = homography1*homography2;
    cv::Mat combined_affine = combined_homog(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 2));

    cv::Mat dst_combined;

    cv::warpAffine(input, dst_combined, combined_affine, input.size());

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("dst1", dst1);
    cv::imshow("dst2", dst2);

    cv::imshow("combined", dst_combined);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, an image is first rotated and translated to the left, later to the right. If the two transformations are performed after each other, significant image areas would get lost. Instead if they are combined by homograhy multiplication, it is like the full operation done in a single step without losing image parts in the intemediate step.

input:

[image]

if image was first transformed with H1, later with H2:

[image]

if the image is transformed with the combination of H1*H2 directly:

[image]

One typical application of this homography combination is to first translate the image center to the origin, then rotate, then translate back to original position. This has the effect as if the image was rotated around its center of gravity.

Comment: Oh Thank you, That should help me a lot and I have to test it asap. I have two questions remaining. What is the unit of alpha ? -13 for 90degrees, I am sorry it must be ovious. I don't know if you have seen but my translation data are for a center of rotation at (0, in.rows), i.e. bottom left corner. It should change the matrix I think.

Comment: Or I can shift at first from (0, in.rows)

Comment: sorry, the unit is degrees. it is -13 degrees, not 90. First I tried 90 degrees, but I wanted to vary it a bit and didnt change the comment. sorry.

Comment: No problem !!! Thank you. If I want add the scale. I multiply scale by cos and sin in the rotation matrix. Am I right ?

Comment: better create another homography for the scale and multiply the homography! maybe that would be the same as multiplying the scale factor to both cos terms only, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same implementation with `opencv-python`.

Affine transformation can be implemented with matrix multiplication (with 6 parameters), hence first having a translation with translation matrix **T**, followed by rotation with rotation matrix **R** is equivalent to affine transformation with matrix **R**x**T**.

Note that we need to transform the transformation matrices to homogeneous coordinates before multiplication, the next code snippet shows the implementation with `opencv-python` using the (padded) cameraman input image:

```
import cv2, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

im = plt.imread('images/cameraman.png')
h, w = im.shape[:2]

tr_mat = np.float32([[1,0,50],[0,1,-50]])
print(tr_mat)
# [[  1.   0.  50.]
#  [  0.   1. -50.]]
out1 = cv2.warpAffine(im, tr_mat, (w,h)) # translation

angle = 30
rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((0,0), -angle, 1.0)
print(rot_mat)
# [[ 0.8660254 -0.5        0.       ]
#  [ 0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]]

out2 = cv2.warpAffine(out1, rot_mat, (w,h)) # rotation

rot_hom = np.append(rot_mat, [[0, 0, 1]], axis=0) # in homogeneous coordinates
tr_hom = np.append(tr_mat, [[0, 0, 1]], axis=0)
rt_mat = rot_hom@tr_hom

print(rot_hom)
# [[ 0.8660254 -0.5        0.       ]
#  [ 0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
#  [ 0.         0.         1.       ]] 

print(rt_mat[:2,:]) # the 6 parameters of the affine transformation
# [[  0.8660254   -0.5         68.30127019]
#  [  0.5          0.8660254  -18.30127019]]
    
out = cv2.warpAffine(im, rt_mat[:2,:], (w,h)) # translation + rotation together

plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.imshow(np.hstack((im, out1, out2, out))), plt.axis('off')
plt.title('input, translated, then rotated, translated+rotated', size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]