# How to position an image using pixel coordinates in python?

Tags: python, image, matrix, kivy

I'm currently working on a personal project that involves `kivy` GUI app maker in `python`.

And I would like to work with images and a `FloatLayout`. The thing is I'm currently stuck because the next step of this project is to position an image to the `FloatLayout` by using coordinates.

Here's an example of what I'd like to happen :

[image: Image positioning]

The blue square is the `FloatLayout`, the orange square is the image, by having at least two points of reference in the `FloatLayout` and inside the image (using pixels as coordinates), the image should go to the '1' and '2' points inside the blue square. `kivy`'s widget `scatter` should do the job of reorienting and scaling the image.

I've thinking about using matrix to somehow solve this problem. I'd appreciate if you recommend me another way to help me achieve this, or link me to a `python` library that works with this specific kind of problems.

Comment: I think you need to do a *"translation"* to move point 1 to 1', followed by a *"rotation"* to move point 2 to 2'. You should be able to use OpenCV's `warpAffine()` function. @Micka has a nice example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911708/2836621

Comment: You can do similar thing with `wand` and probably `scikit-image` and `PIL`.